# apex:iframe inside apex:form

Tags: visualforce, iframe

I have an iframe on my VF page which embedds some other web page where users enter some data. I am using apex:iframe which is inside apex:form. I am just wondering if it will cause any problems if I have apex:iframe without apex:form. VF page saves though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

apex:iframe is a independent component in visualforce page and it doesn't require  as a parent component as some component require. So you can use it without any issue.